# Border bottom to link in menu on hover when having border bottom to the whole menu div

Tags: html, css, web, menu, border

So I am making a menu, but I have encountered the problem of having a menu with a border bottom and links, which on hover have border bottom on the same line as the border of the menu. I have drawn a sample image to help you.

Since I don't have enough reputation click on the link to view the image.
--> http://ctrlv.in/478501 <--

No need to add special effects like colors or movement, just the border. Please help

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you're having?

Comment: I can't seem to make the right hover effect. I make the effect, but the border of the link is above the border of the menu..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
li{
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  float: left;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #CCC;
}

li:hover{
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/at1zvk0a/)

**UPDATE**

[NEW FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/at1zvk0a/1/)

**NEW UPDATE**

[THIRD FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/at1zvk0a/2/)

Comment: Can you make a menu 100% and these li elements in the middle of the menu, then make border-bottom to the menu and then add hover effect to li?

Comment: @TheMetalMonster I updated my answer with a new fiddle

Comment: Still isn't what I am looking for, I have made this thing. The problem is that the border of the li element is above the border of the menu

Comment: @TheMetalMonster ok i think i got it. This isn't dynamic and if you were to add more than 3 links you would have to adjust the percentages, but it works